# JavaScript array push not working with ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-change

I trying to create mark list for a class. When I enter marks for each student,
the push event works. On each change, there will be creating duplication in the array. How can I solve this?

#### View

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in tabledata">
  <td>{{student.RollNumber}}</td>
  <td>{{student.StudentName}}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="item in Allsubjects">
    <div ng-repeat="enable in student.subjectArray">
      <input type="text" 
             class="form-control" 
             ng-model="SubjectMark" 
             ng-change="internal(item.Id,student.StudentId,SubjectMark)" 
             ng-disabled="item.Elective ==='Optional'&& enable.opted != item.Id" 
             required>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

#### JS

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      $scope.ArrayMarks = [];
      $scope.ArrayMarks.push({
        'subject': '',
        'student': '',
        'mark': '',
      });
      $scope.internal = function(Sub, Std, score) {
        if ($scope.ArrayMarks[0].subject === '' && $scope.ArrayMarks[0].student === '') {
          $scope.ArrayMarks.push({
            'subject': Sub,
            'student': Std,
            'mark': score,
          });

          $scope.ArrayMarks.splice(0, 1);

        } else {
          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ArrayMarks.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.ArrayMarks[i].subject === Sub && $scope.ArrayMarks[i].student === Std) {
              $scope.ArrayMarks[i].mark = score;
            } else {
              $scope.ArrayMarks.push({
                'subject': Sub,
                'student': Std,
                'mark': score,
              });

            }
          }
        }
      };
```

This is What I'm getting 
    [(screenshot): there is 9 records instead of 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbM9M.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your `for` loop and ensure adding new entries only if no entry to update was found. Your current solution adds new entries on each loop if no update entry was found.

```
$scope.internal = function(Sub, Std, score) {
  if ($scope.ArrayMarks[0].subject === '' && $scope.ArrayMarks[0].student === '') {
    $scope.ArrayMarks.push({
      'subject': Sub,
      'student': Std,
      'mark': score,
    });

    $scope.ArrayMarks.splice(0, 1);

  } else {

    var found = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ArrayMarks.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.ArrayMarks[i].subject === Sub && $scope.ArrayMarks[i].student === Std) {
        $scope.ArrayMarks[i].mark = score;
        found = true;
      }
    }

    if (!found) {
      $scope.ArrayMarks.push({
        'subject': Sub,
        'student': Std,
        'mark': score,
      });
    }
  }
};
```